# CrudAppService and Filtering in ABP.io

Tags: abp

We've been a long standing ASP.NET Zero user, taking our first foray into ABP.io Commercial.

The online documentation refers to using the CrudAppService() extension which generates a standard CRUD definition for an Entity.

However what does not appear to be part of the CrudAppService, is filtering using the Advanced Filters.

ABP Studio generates code using  and this is confirmed under the Entity Filters section of the commercial documentation. However the generated C# code, doesn't use ICrudAppService, it uses IApplicationService and overrides GetListAsync() in an extension of IRepository to do a custom query.

The EasyCRM sample doesn't use abp-advanced-entity-filters, but does also implement IApplicationService and extends the IRepository model for each entity.

What's the recommendations here?

Can we combine filters with ICrudAppService? Or should we stick with IApplicationService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we combine filters with ICrudAppService? Or should we stick with IApplicationService?

You can combine filters with `ICrudAppService` yes.

- ICrudAppService.cs (https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Ddd.Application.Contracts/Volo/Abp/Application/Services/ICrudAppService.cs#L17-L21) :

```cs
public interface ICrudAppService<TEntityDto, in TKey, in TGetListInput>
    : ICrudAppService<TEntityDto, TKey, TGetListInput, TEntityDto>
{
}
```

As you can see, it expects `TGetListInput` for sorting & filtering & pagination , you can create a class that has the `Filter` property and pass it as `TGetListInput` and then override the `GetListAsync` method in your application service implementation, as done in here:

https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/master/BookStore-Angular-MongoDb/aspnet-core/src/Acme.BookStore.Application/Books/BookAppService.cs#L51-L88

When you do that, all other methods (`GetAsync`, `CreateAsync`, `UpdateAsync` and `DeleteAsync`) would be implemented by the `CrudAppService` class and you would only need to override the `GetListAsync` method for applying filtering.

---

A complete example flow can be as follows:

- MyFilterDto

```cs
public class MyFilterDto : PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto
{
   public string Filter { get; set; }
}
```

- IBookAppService

```cs
public interface IBookAppService :
    ICrudAppService< //Defines CRUD methods
        BookDto, //Used to show books
        Guid, //Primary key of the book entity
        MyFilterDto, //Used for paging/sorting and filtering
        CreateUpdateBookDto> //Used to create/update a book
{
}
```

> Notice: Used MyFilterDto for paging-sorting and filtering!

- BookAppService

```cs
public class BookAppService :
    CrudAppService<
        Book, //The Book entity
        BookDto, //Used to show books
        Guid, //Primary key of the book entity
        PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, //Used for paging/sorting
        CreateUpdateBookDto>, //Used to create/update a book
    IBookAppService //implement the IBookAppService
{
   public async override Task<PagedResultDto<BookDto>>
        GetListAsync(MyFilterDto input)
    {
        //Set a default sorting, if not provided
        if (input.Sorting.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            input.Sorting = nameof(Book.Name);
        }

        //Get the IQueryable<Book> from the repository
        var queryable = await Repository.GetQueryableAsync();

        //Get the books
        var books = await AsyncExecuter.ToListAsync(
            queryable
                .WhereIf(!input.Filter.IsNullOrEmpty(), x => x.Name.Contains(input.Filter)) // apply filtering
                .OrderBy(input.Sorting)
                .Skip(input.SkipCount)
                .Take(input.MaxResultCount)
        );

        //Convert to DTOs
        var bookDtos = ObjectMapper.Map<List<Book>, List<BookDto>>(books);

        //Get a lookup dictionary for the related authors
        var authorDictionary = await GetAuthorDictionaryAsync(books);

        //Set AuthorName for the DTOs
        bookDtos.ForEach(bookDto => bookDto.AuthorName =
                         authorDictionary[bookDto.AuthorId].Name);

        //Get the total count with another query (required for the paging)
        var totalCount = await Repository.GetCountAsync();

        return new PagedResultDto<BookDto>(
            totalCount,
            bookDtos
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. By the looks of it, the key takeaway here, is to override the GetListAsync() method on the CrudAppService so that we can process the parameters on the inbound input filter. ABP.io also seems to move filtering to its own entity specific IRepository.